# Which way do you mount your 416 in the zep?

Tags: microphone, field-recording, sennheiser, how-to

I was wondering. When mounting the MKH416 in a rycote suspension, do you place the opening (grill) area of the mic "top and bottom" so that it is not blocked by the plastic tabs that hold it in place on the Rycote suspension or do you place it "sideways" so that the plastic is covering part of the slotted grill area of the mic?

Hope I explained this question properly! Thanks! If need be I can take pics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a 416...but with shotgun mics in general, i try not to cover the grills. They're an essential part of what makes an interference tube and interference tube. Another relevant point with windscreens is to keep the end from extending beyond the boundary of body and "cap" (the rounded end area) of your windscreen.

Answer (score 1):

" top and bottom " is a good idea if you´re booming above of the person.

BUT,

if you´re miking close to the ground then turn the interference mic, so none of the side grills point to the ground. 
Because if so You get combfiltering sounds that might be audible, especially with the Schoeps CMIT.

Have fun trying out.

Comment: Interesting gonna try that cheers!

Comment: cheers - have fun listening to comb filtering - can sound nice in post, from a creative aspect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another mixer recently suggested mounting it so the brand name sennheiser is on top. That way the polar patterns are most accurately reproduced.